# Avoid events in overlapping elements

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

I have an element with a listener for mousemove events, this element is overlapped by another. I'd like the listener to keep working when the mouse pointer is over the second element, meaning that I want to avoid the mouse event for the element that overlaps the main one, is it possible?

```
<body>
    <div style="position: relative">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" style="background-color: red">
        </canvas>
        <div style="width: 25px; height: 25px; background-color: blue; position: relative; top: -100px; left: 100px" />
    </div>
    <div id="coords"/>
    <script>
        var t = document.getElementById("coords");
        var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
        c.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){
            t.innerText = "x: " + event.layerX + "; y: " + event.layerY;
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You could try to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setCapture using retargetToElement=`true`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've found a solution that seems better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356132/can-i-make-an-element-invisible-to-hovers